# Groovy Scripted field to display result of JIRA JQL

Tags: groovy, jira, jql

I want to get some pointer to write a simple JIRA groovy scripted field – the input is a JQL and the result is the result of the JQL.
For example, if the JQL is "project = RS and fixVersion = 5.0", it will go ahead a list the issues returned from this JQL in the custom field display.

Comment: I am not sure how to get this using Groovy, but we have used a free addon [Query Issues Custom Fields](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ru.mail.jira.plugins.lf.queryfields) by Andrey V Markelov to achieve the same results.

Please let me know if you want more details on how to configure this, will post more steps for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I created a JIRA field called "Fixed Issues JQL", which supposed I will enter the value of "project = VOL and fixVersion = 6.0" in the JIRA.
Then I create a second JIRA custom field , a groovy scripted field called "Fixed Issues List", which contain the following code:

```
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.search.SearchService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserUtil
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.manager.OptionsManager

SearchService searchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchService.class)
UserUtil userUtil = ComponentAccessor.getUserUtil()
User user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

def componentManager = ComponentManager.instance
def optionsManager = ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(OptionsManager.class)
def customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager()
def cf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Fixed Issues JQL")
def myJQL = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf)   // has a value such as "project = VOL and fixVersion = 6.0"

if (!user) {
    user = userUtil.getUserObject('kwhite')
}

List<Issue> issues = null

SearchService.ParseResult parseResult =  searchService.parseQuery(user, myJQL)
if (parseResult.isValid()) {
    def searchResult = searchService.search(user, parseResult.getQuery(), PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
    // Transform issues from DocumentIssueImpl to the "pure" form IssueImpl (some methods don't work with DocumentIssueImps)
    issues = searchResult.issues.collect {issueManager.getIssueObject(it.id)}
} else {
    log.error("Invalid JQL: " + myJQL);
}
```